# Antiscroll native scrollbar visible in IE and Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, scroll, scrollbar

I'm using the antiscroll framework to create an Apple-like scrollbar on my website. More information about the framework can be found here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/antiscroll

I've followed the steps and peeked into the example code which is the file index.html. I tried to reconstruct the example and it works in the Safari and Chrome browser. However, on IE and Firefox the native scrollbar is still visible below the Apple-like scrollbar :(

I don't know what causes this. I've created a JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/BCLE6/2/

```
<div class="antiscroll-wrap">
<div class="antiscroll-inner huurvoorwaarden-wrapper">
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.antiscroll-inner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #BBB;
}
```

And I only have one line JS:

```
$('.antiscroll-wrap').antiscroll();
```

In the fiddle, I've imported the required libraries (jQuery, antiscroll.js, antiscroll.css and jquery.mousewheel.js).

If you open the fiddle in Firefox or IE, you can clearly see the problem. Can someone explain to me why this is happening and what I could do to resolve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to add another div in between the "antiscroll-wrap" and "antiscroll-inner" divs that will be used to cover the scrollbar of the inner div.  This is the markup structure form their example:

```
<div class="box-wrap antiscroll-wrap">
   <div class="box">
      <div class="antiscroll-inner">
         ... 
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You're just missing the div that they've classed as "box".

Answer (score 1):

I suggest increasing the width of your inner, and overflow hidden on your wrapper:

```
.antiscroll-inner {
  background-color: #bbb;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 120px; /** Make 20px larger to extend browser scrollbar outside of wrapper **/
 }

.antiscroll-wrap {
  overflow: hidden; /** Hide overflow **/
  width: 100px; /** Size to what you want, but 20px smaller than inner **/
}
```